# basic c# query

Tags: c#

Im still kinda new to c# and there's something I cant quite get to grips with:

In VBA for example, if there is a bit of code I need throughout an app I would put it in a function then call it where ever I need it just by using the name of the function, eg

```
Sub Something()
    If variable = x then
        RunMyFunction
    end if
End Sub
```

Is there a similar way of calling re-usable code in c#?  I do realise its a completely different beast to what Ive worked with before

thanks

Comment: Is this a joke? No seriously, you don't need an answer from us, you need a course or a good book about (Object-Oriented) programming. Of course there is, it's called a `function`. It's declared closely the same way then in VB(A) `public void testFunc() { Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"); }`. I've voted to close this, just for the records.

Comment: not a joke - just trying to find me way around new stuff

Comment: in c# when you call a function you must add parentheses at the end of the function name , and also a semicolon at the end of each line i.e. myFunction().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I sometimes create a new class called `CommonFunctions.cs`, and inside this class I would have the methods:

```
public class CommonFunctions
{
    public static void Something(int Variable)
    {
        if(Variable == 5)
            CommonFunctions.RunAnother();
    }
    public static void RunAnother()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void Something()
{
   if (variable == x)
   {
      RunMyFunction();
   }
}

private void RunMyFunction()
{
  // does something
}
```

In other words - it is basically the same. You define your resuable function as a method (RunMyFunction above) and then call it by name (with parenthesis).

Comment: You're assigning `x` to `variable` instead of comparing them.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - typo - just testing :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes C# comes with functions as well. Sub is actually a function with `void` "return value".

So crude translation of your code to C# will be:

```
string RunMyFunction()
{
   return "hello";
}

void Something(variable, x)
{
   if (variable == x)
   {
      string value = RunMyFunction();
      //.....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a function:

```
public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
{
    int result = number1 + number2;
    if(result > 10)
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

You might find this article useful:

http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/functions/

The biggest departure you'll need to make from VBA is that C# is truly object-oriented.  You'll have to get used to the idea of functions being a member of a class that you have to instantiate (in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

If your function do not return value use void:

```
private void FunctionName ()
   {
      // Do something...
   }
```

If function return value than function have value type before function name:

```
private int FunctionNameReturnInt(int a, int b)
{     
   // Do something...
   int res = a + b;   
   return num;
}
```

...

```
// Calling functions
FunctionName();

int res;
res = FunctionNameReturnInt(1,2);
```

`